# How do I write this query in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

Suppose I have a datetime column.

```
"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE thetime < INTERVAL 1 HOUR"
```

How do you write this in Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=['thetime < INTERVAL 1 HOUR'])
```